# Determining the Nature of Deduction in a Sentence

Tags: modal-verbs, logic

Does the terminology of *deduction* in this question belong to **logic** or **modal verbs**?

> What does the following sentence express?
> "**Jessica can't be in Italy
> because I saw her in the supermarket today.**"

```
A. Inability
B. Prohibition
C. Positive deduction
D. Negative deduction
```

Comment: You "came across" it? It wouldn't be your homework, then? Read about "Negative deduction" [here.](https://test-english.com/explanation/b2/speculation-deduction-modal-verbs-expressions/)

Comment: Those are technical terms that the average English speaker doesn't necessarily understand. [Philosophy.SE] might be able to help you out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you came across a question without having any idea where it came from. Did it drop out of the sky on a piece of paper? Did someone in your class on English language modal verbs give it to you? If it was online, provide a URL. If it was in a book or worksheet...

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define `modal verb`.  From [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) it's clear `modal verb` is a **linguistic** term for the "can't" in the sentence:

> A modal verb is a type of verb that contextually indicates a [modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modality_(linguistics)) such as a *likelihood, ability, permission, request, capacity, suggestion, order, obligation, necessity, possibility* or *advice*. Modal verbs generally accompany the base (infinitive) form of another verb having semantic content.[1] In English, the modal verbs commonly used are *can, could, may, might, shall, should, will, would, ought to, used to* and *dare*

The term `deduction` belongs to [Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic) as one type of inference as opposed to `induction`.  [This English.SE answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/319307/340832) discusses how to use modal verb to indicate a logical inference:

- Using modal verb "must" as indicating epistemic *a posteriori* (= induction)
- Using modal verb "should" as indicating epistemic *a priori* (= deduction)

@FumbleFingers's [linked article](https://test-english.com/explanation/b2/speculation-deduction-modal-verbs-expressions/) provides more examples on how to use modal verbs for various logical inferences:

> Note that for negative deduction we use **can't** and NOT **<strike>musn't</strike>**.

Thus, to answer your question, *deduction* in options (c) and (d) refer to **logic**.  The right answer is (d).